# Display email address field next to author in wp_dropdown_users

Tags: list-authors

the post_author_meta_box uses wp_dropdown_users showing the user name of authors.
How do I display the email address in brackets next the author's name?
Can one filter the wp_dropdown users do to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only filter hook called in `wp_dropdown_users()` function is `wp_dropdown_users` which pass a string of the dropdown in an html form so you can manipulate this dropdown at that hook with some major REGEX.

A better solution would be to use [get_users()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) and create the dropdown your self, something like this:

```
$selected = 1; //just for example, you can get that by get_post_meta()
$siteusers = get_users(); // you can pass filters and option
$re = '';
if (count($siteusers) > 0){
    $re = '<select name="users_with_email">';
    foreach ($siteusers as $user) {
        $re .= '<option value="' . $user->ID . '">'.$user->user_nicename . ' ('.$user->user_email .')</option>';
    }
    $re .= '</select>';
    $re = str_replace('value="' . $selected . '"','value="' . $selected . '" selected="selected"', $re );
}
echo $re;
```

Comment: I dont want to edit the core, how would one do this with a plugin? Is it possible to replace the wp_dropdown_users() function with my own and not break wp admin elsewhere?

Comment: ok nice.. figured this out thanks to you: http://pastebin.com/RD58LANm