# Select subscriber as author of post in admin panel?

Tags: author, user-roles, capabilities, subscription

I want to be able to select a subscriber an author of a post in the admin so it displays their name as having written the post, but I do not want to give them any additional privileges (if they login the only thing they can access is their profile).

Is there a simple way to do this without having to change roles and capabilities?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a simple hack I wrote in a similar situation. It will display all the `Subscribers` in the `Author` dropdown on edit/add post/page, from where you can select any one you want. I think it should work for you...

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'MySwitchUser');
function MySwitchUser($output)
{

    //global $post is available here, hence you can check for the post type here
    $users = get_users('role=subscriber');

    $output = "<select id=\"post_author_override\" name=\"post_author_override\" class=\"\">";

    //Leave the admin in the list
    $output .= "<option value=\"1\">Admin</option>";
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $sel = ($post->post_author == $user->ID)?"selected='selected'":'';
        $output .= '<option value="'.$user->ID.'"'.$sel.'>'.$user->user_login.'</option>';
    }
    $output .= "</select>";

    return $output;
}
```

The trick behind this is, after you submit submit this page, WP only reads the $user->ID from this drop down in the $_POST array, and assigns it as the posts author. And that's what you want!

Comment: Thanks so much Rutwick! Exactly what I needed! I just had to change $users = get_users(); otherwise it didn't display users with other roles in there

Comment: You're welcome mate! :) Actually I was using it for a custom role, hence the parameters... Glad I could help!

Comment: I've just found a minor issue with this - when I revisit the post edit page the drop down defaults to admin, so if I make changes and save without reselecting the author this it changes the author to admin. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, you get the author for this post, and check which one of users matches the author, keep that option selected.

Comment: For some reason $post->post_author returns nothing in my post edit screen and can't understand why!

Comment: Try printing the `global $post` variable...

Comment: Welcome again :D

Comment: Note that the user ID `1` may or may not be an admin. Fetching a real admin from WordPress would work.

Comment: I've made some minor tweaks to this solution, in case anyone needs.So, if you want to display the "display name" in the dropdown, just change the second line inside foreach to this: $output .= '<option value="'.$user->ID.'"'.$sel.'>'.$user->display_name.'</option>'; And if you want to add some specific user (with different role), add this before foreach: $output .= "<option value=\"[ID]\">Name</option>"; (replace [ID] with actual ID)

Comment: Does what it needs to do!!!

Answer (score 16):

As of WordPress 4.4.0 you can now use the `wp_dropdown_users_args` filter. The code is much simpler now:

```
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_users_args', 'add_subscribers_to_dropdown', 10, 2 );
function add_subscribers_to_dropdown( $query_args, $r ) {

    $query_args['who'] = '';
    return $query_args;

}
```

Comment: This should be the correct/accepted answer. Directly from the Codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_dropdown_users_args/#user-contributed-notes

Answer (score 2):

This is similar approach to @brasofilo. But only works in the edit post screen, rather than quick edit, and includes all users (not just authors and subscribers).

```
/* Remove Author meta box from post editing */
function wpse50827_author_metabox_remove() {
    remove_meta_box('authordiv', 'post', 'normal');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpse50827_author_metabox_remove');


/* Replace with custom Author meta box */
function wpse39084_custom_author_metabox() {  
    add_meta_box( 'authordiv', __('Author'), 'wpse39084_custom_author_metabox_insdes','post');  
 } 
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse39084_custom_author_metabox');  


/* Include all users in post author dropdown*/
/* Mimics the default metabox http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L514 */
function wpse39084_custom_author_metabox_insdes() {
      global $user_ID;
      global $post;
      ?>
      <label class="screen-reader-text" for="post_author_override"><?php _e('Author'); ?></label>

      <?php
        wp_dropdown_users( array(
             'name' => 'post_author_override',
             'selected' => empty($post->ID) ? $user_ID : $post->post_author,
             'include_selected' => true
        ) );
}
```

This mimics the [default author metabox](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L514) but the call `wp_dropdown_users` omits the `who=>'editors'` argument. It defaults to the only other value which is call users.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I ended up using Rutwick's solution because it already works with CPTs but appreciate your answer :)

Comment: added global $post; to the actual function since it wasn't picking up the existing author when I edited a post, but it always took me as post author. Very Annyoing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [code linked](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39107/12615) by @Innate in a comment (solution) to his own question, I've just adapted a little bit and tested in WP 3.3.2 (function wpse39084). 
It will show the subscribers in posts Edit and Quick Edit.

Also added a couple of actions (functions wpse50827) to move the Author meta box inside the Publish Actions meta box, for easier management.

Everything is post related, no pages nor CPTs...

```
foreach( array( 'edit.php', 'post.php' ) as $hook )
    add_action( "load-$hook", 'wpse39084_replace_post_meta_author' );       

/* Show Subscribers in post author dropdowns - edit and quickEdit */
function wpse39084_replace_post_meta_author()
{
    global $typenow;
    if( 'post' != $typenow )
        return;

    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse50827_author_metabox_remove' );
    add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'wpse50827_author_metabox_move' );
    add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_users', 'wpse39084_showme_dropdown_users' );
}

/* Modify authors dropdown */
function wpse39084_showme_dropdown_users( $args = '' )
{
    $post = get_post();
    $selected = $post->post_author;
    $siteusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&order=ASC' ); // you can pass filters and option
    $re = '';
    if( count( $siteusers ) > 0 )
    {
        $re = '<select name="post_author_override" id="post_author_override">';
        foreach( $siteusers as $user )
        {
            $re .= '<option value="' . $user->ID . '">' . $user->user_nicename . '</option>';
        }
        $re .= '</select>';
        $re = str_replace( 'value="' . $selected . '"', 'value="' . $selected . '" selected="selected"', $re );
    }
    echo $re;
}

/* Remove Author meta box from post editing */
function wpse50827_author_metabox_remove()
{
    remove_meta_box( 'authordiv', 'post', 'normal' );
}


/* Move Author meta box inside Publish Actions meta box */
function wpse50827_author_metabox_move()
{
    global $post;

    echo '<div id="author" class="misc-pub-section" style="border-top-style:solid; border-top-width:1px; border-top-color:#EEEEEE; border-bottom-width:0px;">Author: ';
    post_author_meta_box( $post );
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks brasofilo. I ended up using Rutwick's solution because it already works with CPTs but appreciate your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do it...

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'MySwitchUser');
function MySwitchUser()
{
    global $post; // remove if not needed
    //global $post is available here, hence you can check for the post type here
    $users = get_users('role=subscriber');

    echo'<select id="post_author_override" name="post_author_override" class="">';

    echo'<option value="1">Admin</option>';

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$user->ID.'"';

        if ($post->post_author == $user->ID){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }

        echo'>';
        echo $user->user_login.'</option>';     
    }
    echo'</select>';

}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me: it always proposes the Admin account to become new author of the post, which makes it very difficult for users to actually update posts (and then automatically lose editing rights).

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to the accepted answer here but only wanted to show admins and in my case, a custom 'producers' role, together.

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'custom_author_select');
function custom_author_select($output){

    //global $post is available here, hence you can check for the post type here
    $admins = get_users('role=administrator');
    $producers = get_users('role=producer');
    $users = array_merge($admins, $producers);

    $output = "<select id=\"post_author_override\" name=\"post_author_override\" class=\"\">";

    //Leave the admin in the list
    $output .= "<option value=\"1\">Admin</option>";

    foreach($users as $user){
        $sel = ($post->post_author == $user->ID)?"selected='selected'":'';
        $output .= '<option value="'.$user->ID.'"'.$sel.'>'.$user->user_login.'</option>';
    }

    $output .= "</select>";

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution to avoid the error in quick-editing, where "cpt_slug" should be replaced with your custom post type slug

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'MySwitchUser');

function MySwitchUser($output)
{
    global $typenow;
if ((is_edit_page('edit') && "cpt_slug" == $typenow)||(is_edit_page('new') && "cpt_slug" == $typenow)){
    global $post;
    $users = get_users();
    $output = "<select id=\"post_author_override\" name=\"post_author_override\" class=\"\">";   
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $sel = ($post->post_author == $user->ID)?"selected='selected'":'';
        $output .= '<option value="'.$user->ID.'"'.$sel.'>'.$user->user_login.'</option>';
    }
    $output .= "</select>";   
} 
return $output;
}



function is_edit_page($new_edit = null){
    global $pagenow;
    if (!is_admin()) return false;
    if($new_edit == "edit")
        return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php',  ) );
    elseif($new_edit == "new") 
        return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post-new.php' ) );
    else 
        return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a mess. It seems there are 3 ways to go about it, and it depends on whether you are using the Classic Editor or Gutenberg.

If you are using the Classical Editor:

- You can override the HTML using the filter `wp_dropdown_users` as other answers suggested
- Or override the the query parameters using `wp_dropdown_users_args`

If you are using Gutenberg, the Authors dropdown is implemented differently.

As Thomas Levy pointed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gocodebox/lifterlms/issues/752):

> - The block ed. function used to populate the author’s dropdown is
>   [wodpress/data/select( ‘core’ ).getAuthors()](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/94f54892c214ebd014ec126a9575b7e902198ad9/packages/editor/src/components/post-author/check.js#L31)
> - This calls the rest api endpoint:
>   [/wp/v2/users/?who=authors&per_page=-1](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/33d2acb098d5399dbba206b979be54aad015497e/packages/core-data/src/resolvers.js#L28-L31)
> - This api endpoint passes data to WP_User_Query
> - A WP_User_Query with the “who=>author” parameter passed will add a
>   usermeta query [to the mix](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php#L323).
> - This will pull any user with a [user_level not equal to 0](https://codex.wordpress.org/User_Levels#User_Level_Capabilities)

For the custom role to show up in the author dropdown, you need to add the `level_1` capability to the role. Levels were replaced with capabilities in WordPress 2.0 back in 2005, but this behavior/bug stuck around all this time.

```php
$role = add_role( 'mycustomrole', 'My Custom Role' );
$role->add_cap( 'level_1' );
```

To add this capability to existing users, run this once:

```php
$custom_role = get_users( 'role=mycustomrole' );
foreach ( $custom_role as $role ) {
    $role->add_cap( 'level_1' );
}
```