# Change the Author name to a custom field?

Tags: admin, author

In my wordpress backend, is there a way to change the author metabox to display a custom field instead of the user's display_name or username? 
For example, all our users have a custom field 'Organization' which shows their company name. I want this to be displayed in the Author dropdown box on the post.php page instead of the normal id or username. This is to make it easier for our client's web admins to find users(aka companies) faster when creating new posts.
Possible?
We used CIMY Extra User Fields for the additional fields.

Any help would be great.

Comment: So every author has an Organization set?  Do you know if the CIMY plugin just adds the Organization to the user's meta info?

Comment: Pat, I'm assuming CIMY adds it to the meta info, but not sure if it adds it the same way as the regular meta info (ie: website/jabber/etc). Normally we have to call it differently than normal meta data for users.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the code you need to use to call user meta into your question?

Comment: Normally it can be called by this:

` return get_cimyFieldValue($id, 'fieldname'); `

Comment: Update. Ok, i found this: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50827/select-subscriber-as-author-of-post-in-admin-panel/50874#50874] answer, which does give me the custom field (with some hacking), but now it doesn't save the value that i choose, but reverts back to the original author.... how do i save the value selected??

Comment: Please, post your working code.