# `rest_user_query` can't access post author in post edit screen

Tags: hooks, users, rest-api

I'm trying to modify the user dropdown in the post edit screen to show only (a) the current user and (b) the current author of the post. I can't do this using [`wp_dropdown_users_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_dropdown_users_args/) because the meta box in the block editor gets the list of users via a REST query. (`wp_dropdown_users_args` works fine for the user dropdown in the "Quick Edit" form, however.)

[`rest_user_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_user_query/) can modify this dropdown for me, but I can't seem to get any info about the post I'm editing, so I'm unable to determine who the current author is. I can add the current user to the `include` value, but then the dropdown doesn't appear at all (I assume because it has only returned a single user).

What I want to do is something like this, but I don't know how to define the `$POST_AUTHOR` variable here:

```php
function rest_user_filter( $prepared_args, $request = NULL ) {
  $args['include'] = [ get_current_user_id() ];
  array_push( $args['include'], $POST_AUTHOR;
  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'rest_user_query', 'rest_user_filter' );
```

I'd also only like to do this on the post edit screen, of course, too.

Comment: I've posted a reply for this question here if anyone is looking for an answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/418678/27278